# Can't open Leads module in SugarCRM CE 6.5.13

Tags: sugarcrm

We have more then 10 users in SugarCRM CE. We have problem with 2 of them. When these 2 users click on Leads, it doesn't open view Leads. Query that should return values for that page stuck resulting in MySQL consuming 100% CPU time. Other users don't have this problem.

Everything work perfectly. Just for 2 users want open view Leads, they can open Contacts, Opportunities, Emails, but not Leads.

We have before similar problem with another user, and Admin just made new account for that user and everything works ok. Well, now this is not good solution for these 2 users.

So, anyone have idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I've seen this, it's usually from a stored listview order including a field that is no longer seen on the list view, or the field has been deleted from the system. To remedy, have the affected users log into SugarCRM, click their usernames toward the top-right corner to access their user profiles, and click the Reset User Preferences button. This resets all user preferences (but not the user profile, that's separate), including stored listview orders.

Comment: I just try your solution. And it works. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you go and click reset the user preference it will work. But it will log out from the account and you will need to login again